# How do I use xsltproc command-line tools on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, heroku, nokogiri, xslt

In my Ruby on Rails application, I am using xsltproc command-line tools. These work on my development machine, but are not working on Heroku, the deployment platform I am using. I asked Heroku support a question about it, and here is what they said:

```
Hi– can you try compiling xsltproc as a standalone static binary and deploy that as part of your application?
```

If I knew what that meant, I probably wouldn't be here. I am guessing it means make a file with all the xsltproc code and call that for the xsltproc commands. I have no idea how to do that. Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone wants to use xsltproc command-line tools on Heroku, don't do it. I was able to use the Nokogiri gem, along with the built in XPath functions to do everything I need.